# "I'm not bothered by it." or "It doesn't bother me"

Tags: passive-voice

> Sometimes it's noisy here, but it's not a problem. **it doesn't bother me**.

Is the above sentence correct? or Should l use *passive voice*?

> I'm not bothered by it.

Comment: Either is fine.

Comment: No, you don't need a passive voice. *It doesn't bother me* is perfectly fine.